# Regex : select the x first AND the x last letters to replace them

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to select the five first and five last characters to replace them, let's say like for "abcdefgh@abcdefgh.com" to become "*****fgh@abcdefg*****"
The regex i am using doesn't work properly but I can't understand the reason why. Thanks a lot !

`const strRe = str => str.replace(/(^.{5})(.{5}$)/gi, '*****');`

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern `(^.{5})(.{5}$)` does not match, as it should match exactly 10 characters.

You could use an alternation `|` instead to match either 5 chars at the start or 5 char at the end of the string. Note that for the replacement you don't need the capturing groups.

```
str.replace(/^.{5}|.{5}$/
```

```js
let s = "abcdefgh@abcdefgh.com";
const strRe = str => str.replace(/^.{5}|.{5}$/gi, '*****');
console.log(strRe(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it need to be a regex? You can just slice your string:

```
const strRe = str => `*****${str.slice(5, -5)}*****`
```